# Proportionally responsive centered logo and company name area

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm building some responsive WP themes with the idea/hope to make it super-easy for an end-user to setup a simple site that looks good. This is my first attempt at learning responsive as well and can't quite get a complicated logo / company name / tagline feature worked out.  Proportional, centered, unknown widths, oh my!

You can see a mockup of some of the different situations we'd like to handle at http://screencast.com/t/G8O1G4aY.  The left shows a rectangle logo, a square logo, then a square logo with some text and a square logo with more text.

The right side shows how we'd like the responsiveness to look, as the screen gets smaller.  The image starts reducing from a max-height of 200px-ish to 100px-ish and the font-size starts reducing as well.

Hoping to not have to rely on breakpoints to set the sizes.  We've already accepted that were going to have a 'you have JS turned off, its ugly this way' message, so something like http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/ to adjust the font-sizes would be quite alright.

Can it be done??  Can get into more javascript to solve if needed, but hoping for as much CSS handling as possible.

Thanks much for any help!  Keep getting this piece or that - but can't get them all together.

Philip

Comment: Responsive design with dynamic content is a pain lol (something designers can't understand). What exactly is your question (anything can be done!)? Also, you can look into `vmin` units for font sizes... it will scale font size based on viewport size without the need for javascript. But be warned it may not be supported everywhere

Comment: Thanks zgood, I just can't seem to get everything to work together.  I'm not sure I'm heading in the right direction even, but got stuck in my last attempt when trying to get the div with the logo and/or text centered, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPepqd.  Not sure if there is a better structure to start with - or if I need to start looking to javascript to center for the next step, etc.

Comment: I have updated your code pen to get your yellow div centered with minimal changes ([see here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYZpKQ)). You should also take a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's a css property that was built to deal with fluid, dynamic layouts

Comment: I had tried translateX at one point - problem is that it keeps the 50% margins even at small sizes, instead of letting it take up the whole screen.  Very cool about flexbox, don't think I can get away with that browser support though.  I'm resigned to using js to get all this done now, so went ahead and just forced some css based on actual width to center, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNOqLr.  Stuck now trying to get the logo to resize based on the height of its parent.  Any ideas on that?  Thanks again!